# Displaying a taxonomy term description in the select list

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

Select lists have a name|value pair structure. In the case of taxonomy tid|term name.

In order to make data entry faster, people would like the term name in the select list to include the description. e.g. USD - US dollars

How to alter the select list to display the description?

- The name could be changed to USD - US dollars. This might work, although in exporting the data, the shortened name is required.
- An entity browser works nicely, although it slows down the editing process and takes more effort to integrate with ajax.

Comment: Where is the select list being used? If it's the field widget, you could try a custom field widget: https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-field-widget

Comment: Yes in a content type.